# Let $x_{0}=1$ and $x_{1}=-1$ For $n\geq0$ inductively define $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}+6x_{n}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, wavelets

I am not so sure how to do this problem and would like some help here. How would you induct a relation given this information here?  I mean I know what induction means but I'm not so sure what I'm being asked to do.

Comment: I guess the task is to find the general term, given the first two terms and the recurrence relation.

Comment: You mean you want a closed form? Or maybe prove by induction?

Comment: I just have to find a formula for $x_{n}$ I guess... but how?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve it :
you can solve it by Characteristic equation $$x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}+6x_n\\r^2=r+6\\r^2-r-6=0\\(r-3)(r+2)=0\\r=3,-2\\$$so $x_n$ must be like this $$x_{n}=c_1r_1^n+c_2r_2^n\\x_n=c_1(3)^n+c_2(-2)^n\\$$now apply $x_1=-1,x_0=1$ to find $c_1,c_2$ 
at the end $$ x_{n}=\frac{1}{5}(3)^n+\frac{4}{5}(-2)^n$$ you can easily see $x_2=5$ and so on ...